# AngularJS and Django ReST Framework Duplicate POST

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and the Django ReST Framework to create several API endpoints to manipulate some simple data models.  I have an issue where I iterate over an array and create an object that I POST to the Django ReST API.  The for loop in question could have from 0 to X POST requests that it needs to complete.  Whenever that amount is above 1 the results are completely arbitrary.

Here is the code that calls the create function which calls POST:

```
$scope.updatePermissions = function(currentWallPermissions) {
    var newWallPermission = {};
    var permissionsToDelete = [];

    //Handle deletions
    for (var x=0; x < currentWallPermissions.length; x++) {
        var foundPermissionFlag = 0;

        // Does the current permission in teh for loop exist in the user permissions
        for (var y=0; y < $scope.selectedWalls.length; y++) {
            if (currentWallPermissions[x].wall_id === $scope.selectedWalls[y].id) {
                foundPermissionFlag = 1;
            }
        }

        // What to do with deletions
        if (foundPermissionFlag !== 1) {
            ModelUtils.del("/api/userperms/", currentWallPermissions[x]);
        }
    }

    newWallPermission.user_id = $scope.currentWallUser.id;

    //Handle additions
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.selectedWalls.length; i++) {
        var oldPermissionFlag = 0;

        // Does the current permission in the for loop exist in the user permissions
        for (var j=0; j < currentWallPermissions.length; j++) {
            if ($scope.selectedWalls[i].id == currentWallPermissions[j].wall_id) {
                oldPermissionFlag = 1;
            }
        }

        // Do this for new permissions only
        // No action taken for old permission entries - they already exist
        if (oldPermissionFlag !== 1) {
            newWallPermission.wall_id = $scope.selectedWalls[i].id;
            ModelUtils.create("/api/userperms/", newWallPermission, $scope.errors);
        }
    }

    $scope.getUsers();
    $scope.getWalls();
};
```

Here is the code that creates the promise of a POST:

```
var ModelUtils = {
    get: function(url, id) {
        $http.get(url + id + '/').success(function(response){response.data});
    },
    create: function(url, obj, errors) {
        alert("CREATE\n" + JSON.stringify(obj));
        return $http.post(url, obj).
            success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                angular.extend(obj, response);
            }).
            error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                handleErrors(response, status, errors);
            });
    },
    save: function(url, obj, errors) {
        alert("SAVE\n" + JSON.stringify(obj));
        if (angular.isDefined(obj.id)) {
            return $http.put(url + obj.id + '/', obj).
                    success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                        angular.extend(obj, response);
                    }).
                    error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                        handleErrors(response, status, errors);
                    });
        } else {
            return this.create(url, obj, errors);
        }
    },
    del: function(url, obj) {
        return $http.delete(url + obj.id + '/');
    }
};
```

The problem is that when $scope.selectedWalls.length > 1 the ModelUtils.create promise ends up sending the wrong data to the Django server I end up with multiple entries with the same data.  The even larger problem is that I have the model in Django set for unique_together on the two fields the model has, so multiple entries with the same data should NOT be possible.

Here is the JSON object that I am POSTing:

```
{
    "user_id": null,
    "wall_id": null
}
```

null would be a number.  The problem is that the same numbers are sent for every POST.  Notice the alert boxes I have in the ModelUtils code.  The data that shows up there is correct.  However, the data being sent to the server is incorrect.

I can provide more information if needed.  Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: I'm closing this myself.  Sorry to anyone that invested any time in trying to help me.  It turned out to be a simple problem with my `newWallPermission` variable.  I moved it to just below: 
    
    `for (var i=0; i < $scope.selectedWalls.length; i++) {`

And now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this myself.  Sorry to anyone that invested any time in trying to help me.  It turned out to be a simple problem with my `newWallPermission` variable.  I moved it to just below:

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.selectedWalls.length; i++) {
```

And now it works fine.